# Put cursor at the end of textarea after adding text

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, textarea

I'm trying to make a button to give a comment on someone's profile page. The JavaScript now adds the '@username' to the text area so some kind of mention is made. This works very well. The only problem is, that when I try to focus to the text area after the mention has been added, the cursor is put in before of the text, and not after.

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="pull-right"onclick='document.getElementById("comment").value = "@username"; document.section.comment.focus();'>Click to comment</a>
```

And for the text area

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Write comment here" ></textarea>
```

```html
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="pull-right" onclick='document.getElementById("comment").value = "@username "; document.section.comment.focus();'>Click to comment</a>

<br><br>
<form action='' method="POST" name="section">
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Write your comment" ></textarea><!-- <p id="reageer_op"></p> -->
</form>
```

I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Is there a solution without jQuery? I found this solution with jQuery here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/mover-cursor-to-end-of-textarea/

Comment: JQuery === JavaScript. There is nothing that JQuery does that can't be done with vanilla JavaScript because JQuery is written in vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself, add the following to the script of the button

```
document.section.comment.setSelectionRange(document.section.comment.value.length,document.section.comment.value.length);
```

```html
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="pull-right" onclick='document.getElementById("comment").value = "@username "; document.section.comment.focus();document.section.comment.setSelectionRange(document.section.comment.value.length,document.section.comment.value.length);'>Click to comment</a>

<br><br>
<form action='' method="POST" name="section">
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Write your comment" ></textarea><!-- <p id="reageer_op"></p> -->
</form>
```

This did the trick! Thanks anyways!

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question/answer is meaningless. Include your code in a "code snippet", right in your question/answer.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Thanks for the addition here. Is this new on SO? I've added the snippet now.

Comment: Nope. Snippets have been around for years.